# How to use @ConstructorResult annotation

Tags: java, jpa, nativequery

I have some native query and want to map the result of query execution into List of NON-Entity POJO classes:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "SomeMapping",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = SomeClass.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "NAME", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "DATE_BEGIN", type = java.util.Date.class)
            }
        )
    }
)

public class SomeClass{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private java.util.Date begDate;
    private java.util.Date endDate;

    public SomeClass(Integer id, String name, Date begDate){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.begDate = begDate;
    }

    //Getters & Setters ...
}
```

And generally how i want to retrieve result of query execution:

```
String query = "SELECT " +
"A.id AS 'id', " +
"A.name AS 'NAME', " +
"A.begDate AS 'DATE_BEGIN' " + 
"FROM " +
"SomeTable A " +
"WHERE A.endDate < '2014-01-01'";

List<SomeClass> result = em.createNativeQuery(query, "SomeMapping").getResultList();
```

But i always get the List of Object. How to retrieve list of my POJO-s?

Comment: That is a good explanation for issues
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160817/getting-error-could-not-locate-appropriate-constructor-on-class?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: None of the answers seem to address the question. I'm facing the same issue. Looks like Spring/JPA makes it difficult to map a native/non-native query results to a simple POJO. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce, but your code have some problems.

- add `@SqlResultSetMapping` on entity classes
- don't quote column alias name with `'`

```java
import java.util.Date;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SomeClass {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateBegin;
}
```

```java
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;

@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "SomeMapping",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = SomeClass.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "NAME", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "DATE_BEGIN", type = java.util.Date.class)
            })
    })
@Entity
@Table(name = "sometable")
@Getter
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "begdate")
    private Date begDate;

    @Column(name = "enddate")
    private Date endDate;
}
```

```java
        final String query = "SELECT " +
            "A.id AS id, " +
            "A.name AS NAME, " +
            "A.begDate AS DATE_BEGIN " +
            "FROM " +
            "SomeTable A " +
            "WHERE A.endDate < '2014-01-01'";

        final List<SomeClass> result = em.createNativeQuery(query, "SomeMapping").getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `@SqlResultSetMapping` entity on a Entity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I have not tried it, but I believe it IS the answer. The fact that I formulated it like a "try" has nothing to do with its correctness. PS: you can be sure, if I get any reaction from OP, I will change the text correspondingly.

Comment: If i move "@SqlResultSetMapping" annotation to another Entity-class (with "@Entity" annotation) I recieve empty list. But executing same query in HeidySQL returns multiple rows.